# Definition of a separating triangle in planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, hamiltonian-path

In Bill Tutte's famous book *Graph Theory as I Have Known It* he discusses Hassler Whitney's theorem on Hamiltonian cycles in planar graphs, summarising it thus:

> Any strict triangulation in which there is no separating triangle has a Hamiltonian circuit.

That is fairly clear, and to me a "separating triangle" is one which, if removed, would separate the graph.

But Tutte defines it the following way:

> By a "separating triangle" of a planar map is meant a circuit of three edges that is not the boundary of a face; it has at least two faces of the map inside and at least two outside.

I don't understand this...

1. Surely a circuit of three edges circumscribes a triangle, and therefore by definition must be the boundary of a face.
2. How can a circuit of **three** edges have more than one face inside it? For >3 edges, that's clear, but not for 3.

And how does this way of defining a separating triangle square up with more usual definitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us be very careful here and make a clear distinction between an abstract graph and a planar embedding. We recapitulate the following definitions:

**Def. 1:** Let $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be any open set. Being linked by an arc in $\mathcal{O}$ defines an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{O}$. The corresponding equivalence classes are again open. They are the regions of $\mathcal{O}$.

**Def. 2:**
A closed set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is said to separate a region $\mathcal{O}'$ of $\mathcal{O}$ if $\mathcal{O}' \setminus X$ has more than one region.

**Def. 3:**
The frontier of a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is the set $Y$ of all points $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that every neighborhood of $y$ meets both $X$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus X$. Note that if $X$ is open then its frontier lies in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus X$.

**Def. 4:**
A plane graph (or planar map) is a pair $(V,E)$ of finite sets with the following properties (the elements of $V$ are again called vertices, those of $E$ edges):

1. $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.
2. Every edge is an arc between two vertices.
3. Different edges have different sets of endpoints.
4. The interior of an edge contains no vertex and no point of any other edge.

**The abstract graph of a plane graph is called planar graph.**

**Def. 5:**
When $G$ is a plane graph, we call the regions of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus G$ the faces of $G$. These are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and hence have their frontiers in $G$. Since $G$ is bounded, exactly one of its faces is unbounded. This face is the outer face of $G$. The other faces are its inner faces.

**Def. 6:** An embedding in the plane, or planar embedding, of an abstract graph $G$ is an isomorphism between $G$ and a plane graph $G'$.

**Example:**  Given a plane graph $G'=(V,E)$ with $V=\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}$ and $E=\{(v_0,v_1),(v_0,v_2),(v_1,v_2)\}$. $G'$ is isomorphic to $K_3$, a complete graph on three vertices. Define $X=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus G'$, $X$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. $X$ is the union of two disjoint subsets $I=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (G' \cup O)$ and $O=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (G' \cup I)$. They are the regions of $X$ and are by definition again open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Consider the following figure:
[image]

Now, consider the following:

**Def. 7:** A triangle $t$ of a planar graph $G$ is called faced if there
exists a plane embedding $G'$ of $G$ such that $t$ is a face of $G'$; otherwise $t$ is called faceless.

**Example:** Consider the graph $G'$ given by the following figure:
[image]

The triangle given by the vertex set $\{u,v,w\}$ is obviously a faceless triangle. It is easy to see topologically as well: The interior of $\{u,v,w\}$ is not arc-connected in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus G'$, and hence not a single region. Notice as well that the triangle $\{u,v,w\}$ has multiple faces in its interior.

To summarize, a "circuit" is a graph in an abstract sense. The planar embedding of a circuit $G$ is a plane graph $G'$ isomorphic to $G$. The definition of a face does not exist for $G$ but for $G'$. It follows easily what he means by a "separating triangle".

**References:**

[1] Reinhard Diestel. Graph Theory (Graduate Texts in mathematics). 5th ed. Vol. 173. Springer, 2017.

[2] C. M. (Kieka) Mynhardt and Christopher M. van Bommel. Triangle Decompositions of Planar Graphs. 2015.

Comment: A beautiful answer coupled with some really helpful examples too. Thank you for it. Am still digesting it fully...

Comment: You are welcome. If anything is still unclear, do not hesitate to ask. I'd be happy to append some more explaination to the answer.